# How to copy the whole blender file into a new one without losing collections?

Tags: scene, collections

Sometimes a scene that will have some unsolvable error, the easiest way is to copy everything to a new blend file scene but with that, everything goes into one collection instead of how it was in my previous file that would be very organized. any workaround ?

Comment: Maybe export it? and then reimport it, or literally copy paste the information between 2 blender windows?

Comment: try appending the file.  file>append

Comment: Hi :). You can append the whole scene, or collections into a new file. Simply drag'n'drop your old file over a new blender window > Append.